# Xcode Swift Ios App: Adding delay

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, timer, delay

I am working on a simple quiz game and i want to add some little delays to the game,now when i select the answer the game goes instantly to the next answer now i want to change the color of the button for 0.1 seconds and then loads the next question

I tried the sleep function but it adds only the delay without the color change and i can't choose time intervals smaller than a second because it accepts integers as value

here is the code

```
sender.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
sleep(1)
sender.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
```

what i have to put instead of sleep to obtain what i want?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `NSTimer` for that, firstly you implement `NSTimer` and you add duration time 1.0 second or what ever want then, pass the time `NSTimer` call its function and you change questions to another

Comment: i was already using timers,i added another one for the change of the color and it worked, thank you

Answer (score 5):

If you only need a sleep function, just use

```
NSThread.sleepForTimeInterval(1)
```

Comment: i tried put this line between the two change color instructions,it adds the delay but doesn't change color

Comment: Want to make it clear that this blocks the thread. As well as `sleep()` does. This does not solve GioB's issue.

Answer (score 2):

Use **usleep** which takes an int in microseconds. (i.e. 1,000,000 microseconds is equivalent to 1 second) So for 0.1s use:

```
       // Sleep for 0.1s
       usleep(100000)
```

Recommend to use in a background thread. You certainly don't want to be doing this on the main UI Thread!

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try NSTimer or dispatch_after to do such things:(The NSTimer may be not so convenient as it needs a class method used as call back selector)

```
sender.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
dispatch_after(#your time#, 
  dispatch_get_main_queue()){
  sender.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
  #load your new question logic#
}
```

P.S.:The performSelector:delay: method is not available in Swift.